# Can apache superset be used for ad hoc reporting? 9Something similar to Report Builder feature of MicroStrategy)

Tags: apache-superset

We want to setup Apache Superset as an enterprise BI solution. Earlier solution used is MicroStrategy. It provides Report Builder feature which helps users to build a report based on the prompts. They choose columns and metrics that they want on the reports. How can the Apache Superset be used to provide ad-hoc reporting to the users?

Tried SQL Templating. It does work to a descent extent. However I want to explore what other users have done with respect to the ad-hoc reporting and Apache Superset.